# Когда использовать form html

Tags: html, css

Немного запутался. Пробую верстать по psd и иногда смотрю на пример(исходный код - как должно было бы быть). Так вот, там блок логина-пароля и кнопки сделаны через div отдельно для каждого и далее уже задана фоновая картинка для diva и цвет текста и т.д для input'a. Я же пытался сделать это через форму объединив в ней все три input'a для логина, пароля и кнопу. Как лучше? И как правильнее?

Как сделано:

```
<div class="form_header">
    <span class="sign_in">Sign In</span>
    <div class="sign">  
        <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="sign">  
        <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Go">
    <span>|</span>
    <span class=sign_up><a href="#">Sign Up</a></span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждую форму стоит оборачивать в тэг `form` для логического обозначения того, что это форма. Также стоит указывать правильные типы полей ввода. Валидная верска позволяет правильно разбирать вашу страницу поисковыми роботами

Ознакомиться с назначением элементов html можно здесь https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp.

Для более глубокого понимания читайте спецификацию https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html.

P.S. Не все примеры в сети могут правильными

Answer (score 1):

Когда вёрстка будет закончена, и наступит время натягивать всё это дела на движок, или прикручивать back-end, удобнее будет если будет присутствовать тег form, который будет делать запрос в php файл для обработки(или в другой файл, который выполнит действия над входящей инфой). Поэтому, не только с точки зрения валидности, понимания браузером и т.д. но и с той точки зрения, что будет присутствовать back-end(а раз есть логин-пароль - он там будет присутствовать).
И ещё, если юзать бутстрап - для оформления лучше запихивать label и input в див с классом form-control(или что-то вроде этого, погугли bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Логичнее оба поля и кнопку обернуть одной формой, но в вашем коде ее пока вообще нет.

Comment: Почему и зачем нужно оборачивать в форму?

Comment: @EmptyMan, это валидная разметка, согласно спецификации https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html . Роботам проще правильно понимать ваш сайт, применять автозаполнение для форм

Comment: по той же причине "Роботам проще правильно понимать ваш сайт" со временем лучше отходить от классических form и перейти на использование ajax с прямым вытаскиванием данных из input.